# How to remove all npm packages on mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, yeoman

I have mistake i install two packages (grunt and after that yeoman) but with sudo... i wish i do that in other way so i need to delete those two packages...

When i run command npm uninstall yeoman -g or npm remove yeoman -g    with sudo or without i get this error

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules: "yeoman"
zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/username/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt             
 ~ [05:54:26]
```

So how can i delte that :S

Comment: it doesn't seem to be installed.. what does `npm ls yeoman` output?

Comment: Trying to delete for the same reasons. Same error.